# Is this the only eclipse where Moon's shadow on the Earth (umbra) has been photographed by a person in space?

Tags: astronauts, space-station, photography, solar-eclipse

In [this nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GIjfkFucSs) musing about (among other things) the US Naval Observatory's $3,500 expedition to [Baker City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker_City,_Oregon) or at least [Baker County](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker_County,_Oregon) Oregon to observe the June 18, 1918 solar eclipse, there is also one of the [photos of a penumbral shadow taken by the Expedition 12 crew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_12#Solar_eclipse) during the [March 29, 2006 solar eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_March_29,_2006).

Have there been others? One additional example would be sufficient for an answer. I'm curious how many different solar eclipse penumbral shadows on the Earth have been photographed by people from space, but one more is good enough for this question. Thanks!

---

**below:** Screenshot from the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GIjfkFucSs), photo credits available at the end.

[image]

Comment: There should be some pictures taken by weather satellites.

Comment: Some satellite images:  
https://www.space.com/32215-total-solar-eclipse-2016-satellite-photos.html  
https://www.yahoo.com/news/solar-eclipses-shadow-caught-spectacular-satellite-photo-160129142.html  
http://www.cbsnews.com/news/moons-shadow-on-earth-from-ring-of-fire-eclipse-seen-from-space/  
https://thespacereporter.com/2016/03/satellite-images-show-solar-eclipse-space/  
https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap170717.html

Comment: Another very good one: https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/30758

Comment: @Uwe I don't know the exact figures, but probably the Earth has been photographed with complete coverage (except the poles) at least once per hour (maybe per 2-hours in the beginning) for the last fifty years. It's probably safe to say that *every penumbral shadow for the last fifty years has been photographed by satellites*. These penumbral shadows last for many hours as they slowly move. I'd be surprised if there was one non-polar-region penumbra that hasn't been.

Comment: You mean the moon's shadow ?

Comment: @Antzi Indeed, I meant "Moon's shadow on the Earth" rather than "Earth's shadow". Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another, not as nice, taken March 20, 2015 by Samantha Cristoforetti.

[image]

From [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/astrosamantha/16686549769/in/album-72157651047516588/)

There is a whole [article](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-081617a-total-solar-eclipse-from-space-astronauts.html) on this on collectspace with other examples. Here's one from Mir in 1999.
[image]
And one from the ISS in 2002
[image]

Added one taken by ISS crewmember Paolo Nespoli on August 21 2017.
[image]

Comment: The page says "I think this is it: the umbra." The umbra of an eclipse should be completely black. Every eclipse is different, but they are around ~100 km wide, sometimes more, sometimes less or zero or even below (in the case of annular eclipses where *there is no umbra*. I'll check out the details tomorrow - the position of the Sun, Moon, and ISS can be easily extracted with Skyfield and we can see if there was an umbra viewable at the time. It might be just beyond the terminator here. Looks good, thanks!

Comment: This one was way up near the north pole, so it may have been a bit of a challenge; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SE2015Mar20T.png

Comment: @uhoh a timely article was published on collectspace, I have updated my answer.

Comment: These are really excellent! Thanks for the follow-up. For some reason I've never heard about this until I saw that video but after reading your linked article I can see that astronauts have been seeing these shadows all along. Thanks!

Comment: I stopped by to [mention this](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-082117b-solar-eclipse-space-station-astronauts.html) but you've already updated your post - excellent! It says they saw this shadow on three consecutive passes. It goes on to say that "It was only the seventh time that a spacecraft's crew had seen a total solar eclipse (as visible from the Earth) in the almost 60 years of human spaceflight." and links to [Total view: A brief history of solar eclipses seen from space](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-081617a-total-solar-eclipse-from-space-astronauts.html)

Comment: Astronaut Randy Bresnik's eclipse tweets: [1](https://twitter.com/AstroKomrade/status/899912955508252676), [2](https://twitter.com/AstroKomrade/status/899910214484459520) and [3](https://twitter.com/AstroKomrade/status/899909528216535044).

Comment: I just ran across Don Pettit's  [tweeted video](https://twitter.com/astro_Pettit/status/894704410168770560) and [tweeted photo](https://twitter.com/astro_Pettit/status/894230025599320066)