# Has the Moon's shadow on the Earth (solar eclipse umbra) ever been photographed from beyond Earth orbit?

Tags: spacecraft, photography, solar-eclipse

[Here is a great answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22656/12102) with photos of the shadow of the moon on the Earth's surface (umbra) during a total solar eclipse, taken by *real people in space*, and links to even more of them. I think there's been about seven in total (see [here](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-081617a-total-solar-eclipse-from-space-astronauts.html) and [here](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-082117b-solar-eclipse-space-station-astronauts.html)).

But has the Moon's shadow on the Earth (solar eclipse umbra) ever been photographed from beyond Earth orbit? For this question photos by satellites are of course fine!

Comment: We don't send much spacecraft beyond earth orbit, and when we do, they tends not to linger much long in earth vicinity where they could take a picture of a relatively rare event.  Besides, they usually have much better things to do during this short time than expand monopropellant to orient their limited telephoto lens towards earth.

Comment: If you mean the LRO picture, since it is on the moon, which is in earth orbit, I thought it would be disqualified by your requirements. (A deep space picture).

Comment: From https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_(mathématiques) and the transitivity rule (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation ) , Given Earth orbit E and Moon M;   (E⊂M and  M⊂LRO) => E⊂LRO

Comment: @Antzi I have just asked [How many spacecraft have taken a “Pale Blue Dot” type photo of the Earth from beyond cis-lunar space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22838/12102) and I think you will be surprised at the number of spacecraft that have done so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Earth Polychromatic Imaging Camera (EPIC)](https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/epic) on the [Deep Space Climate Observatory (DSCOVR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Climate_Observatory) spacecraft has observed both the [2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_March_9,_2016) and [2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_August_21,_2017) eclipses and probably every solar eclipse since it's arrived, as EPIC is always looking at the sunlit part of Earth.  DSCOVR is at the Sun-Earth [L₁ point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point), roughly 4× farther out than the Moon.

2016 (edited and zoomed in):

[image: DSCOVR eclipse photo]
Source: [NASA](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/NaturalHazards/view.php?id=87675).

2017 (entire disk, straight from image browser):
[image: DSCOVER eclipse photo 2017]
Source: [NASA](https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/?date=2017-08-21)

You can browse photos for yourself at the [EPIC browser](https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/?date=2017-08-21), searching for 2017-08-21 and you'll see the so-called “Great American Eclipse” soon enough.

NASA also produced an animation at of the 2016 eclipse at:

https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/NaturalHazards/view.php?id=87675

Sun-Earth L₁ is 1.5 million km from Earth, which is farther than the Moon, which has a semi-major axis of 384,000 km.

---

Although it didn't seem to happen during the eclipse, during the solar eclipse or indeed any new Moon, the Moon can't be very far from the field of view of EPIC.  Indeed, sometimes the Moon "photo bombs":

[image: not an eclipse]

---

Not quite as far away is the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter (LRO), which took the following photo during the 2017 total eclipse.  Note that during a solar eclipse (and any new moon) the entire disk of the Earth is sunlit as seen from the moon:

[image: LRO eclipse photo]

Comment: Lissajous orbits are Heliocentric orbits that are a bit wiggly because they are modified by the Earth a bit, but they are not in Earth orbit. Very nice!

Comment: Did you want to include the other satellite's recent photos in your answer? Eventually I'll post it as another answer if nobody else does.

Comment: @uhoh I am not sure what other satellite you mean.  Do you mean LRO?

Comment: ya, it's in orbit around the Moon. If the Earth disappeared tomorrow it would stay in orbit around the moon. So I think it's safe to say that it's not in orbit around the Earth. It's not LRO's fault that the Moon just happens to be in orbit around the Sun. For example, when something is in LEO we don't say that it is in orbit around the Sun, even though we know the Earth is in orbit around the Sun. In an inertial frame, DSCOVER circles around the Earth once a year, but we don't call that an Earth orbit either. So LRO counts for this question at least.

Comment: @uhoh Added that one and another photo where the moon photobombs EPIC.  Next time we have an eclipse at the same latitude of the sub-solar-point that's bound to happen simultaneously!

Comment: The DSCOVR orbit - the actual position in space in J2000 xyz coordinates can be obtained from [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi), but they also make available all of the satellite data for each image in the database, so you could theoretically reconstruct the whole relative orientation of the Sun, Moon, Earth and DSCOVER quartet to tens of meters of accuracy, limited by the how many decimal places the exposure time is given of course. Easily to tens of kilometers.

Comment: The short answer is that DSCOVR's Lissajous orbit probably just has it far enough away from the Earth-Sun line that it looks around the moon. The way that the moon photobombed Earth in that nice photo is that it was ALSO far away from the Earth-Sun line, thanks to it's orbit's inclination relative to the ecliptic. Thanks for the additional photo, these make a beautiful set! :-)

Comment: @uhoh I don't know if there's a lot of black space that's cropped away in EPIC images, or if published images correspond to the actual field of view of the instrument.  If the former, perhaps it did see the moon; it just didn't block any view of Earth.  Either way, I've posted [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22848/33) which I can probably answer if I bother to take the time to browse through future eclipses :)

Comment: "[EPIC has an aperture diameter of 30.5 cm (12 in), a focal ratio of 9.38, a field of view of 0.61°, and an angular sampling resolution of 1.07 arcseconds. Earth's apparent diameter will vary from 0.45° to 0.53° full width.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Climate_Observatory#EPIC)" It's sized specifically for the disk of the Earth.

Answer (score 2):

You can now see a smooth animation of the last 8/21 eclipse using the Blueturn app:

http://app.blueturn.earth/?date=2017-08-21_15-35-54

More generally, this app interpolates EPIC images received from DSCOVR using relat-time 3D projection techniques. In such this is the first and only interactive video of the Whole Earth, with 2+ year of data. Very recommended!

Comment: It's a web app, nothing gets installed on your machine

Comment: @uhoh Yes indeed I answered several questions related to DSCOVR with a link to my app, as I thought it is relevant, and I want to make it known by the space community. It is a free app, with no ads. It exists as a web  app or as a mobile app (Android or iOS) if you open it from your phone or tablet.
Enjoy, and sorry if it may have felt obnoxious.

Comment: @Mic thanks for the reply - OK that sound great. Looking forward to it!