# How many spacecraft have taken a "Pale Blue Dot" type photo of the Earth from beyond cis-lunar space?

Tags: deep-space, photography, pale-blue-dot

How many spacecraft have taken a "Pale Blue Dot" type photo of the Earth from deep space?

A "Pale Blue Dot" type photo would be a photo of the earth from far away; for the purposes of this question it can be anything outside of cis-lunar space. See for example the NASA news article ['Pale Blue Dot' Images Turn 25](https://www.nasa.gov/jpl/voyager/pale-blue-dot-images-turn-25) and the question[What is the brown band in which we find the pale blue dot that is Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20125/12102) for the original Pale Blue Dot image, and [this great answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/3758/12102) for more cool photos!

I have a random collection, there are quite a few in fact. If someone has or know of a complete list and can post it, that would be great. If this needs to be changed to a community wiki, that's fine. Ideally one sample image from each spacecraft would be super, maybe this has been done already somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Cassini](https://science.nasa.gov/science-research/earth-science/23jul_palebluedot/) and Voyager 1 are the only ones to take a photo from the outer solar system.

From Mars, [MRO](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/earth-and-its-moon-as-seen-from-mars), [Curiosity](https://www.nasa.gov/jpl/msl/earth-view-from-mars-pia17936), and [Spirit](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/gallery/press/spirit/20040311a.html) all have.

From Mercury, [MESSENGER](http://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/earth/earth-and-the-moon-from-mercury.html) did.

Deep Space- [Deep Impact](http://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/earth/moon-transiting-earth-deep-impact-sequence.html)

If there are any others, I can't find them. Of course, many have taken them from the Moon, or in Earth lagrange points, or during flybys of the Earth, but for those, take a look at this [Planetary Society](http://planetary.org/explore/space-topics/earth/pics-of-earth-by-planetary-spacecraft.html) list.

Answer (score 4):

> How many spacecraft have taken a "Pale Blue Dot" type photo of the Earth from beyond cis-lunar space?

I'd say 9,660,000 km counts as "beyond cis-lunar. From a Aug. 30, 2011 NASA JPL news article [Jupiter-Bound Space Probe Captures Earth And Moon](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/jupiter-bound-space-probe-captures-earth-and-moon):

> This image of Earth (on the left) and the moon (on the right) was taken by NASA's Juno spacecraft on Aug. 26, 2011, when the spacecraft was about 6 million miles (9.66 million kilometers) away. It was taken by the spacecraft's onboard camera, JunoCam. The solar-powered Juno spacecraft lifted off from Cape Canaveral Air Force Station in Florida on Aug. 5 to begin a five-year journey to Jupiter. Credit: NASA/JPL-Caltech/SwRI

[image: This image of Earth (on the left) and the moon (on the right) was taken by NASA's Juno spacecraft on Aug. 26, 2011, when the spacecraft was about 6 million miles (9.66 million kilometers) away. It was taken by the spacecraft's onboard camera, JunoCam.]

click for larger size